# Filtering at create - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to check if new submissions match certain aspects of existing submissions and, if so, prevent it from being created.

```rb
if ( !Book.exists?(author: @book.author) and 
!Book.exists?(publisher: @book.publisher) ) 
or 
( !Book.exists?(name: @book.name) and 
!Book.exists?(genre: @book.genre) )

...create
```

The problem is that if the genre and the publisher match existing records, the book is not created. That's clearly not what I intend with those operators. I tried && and || and also mixed them with and *and or*, knowing && and || take precedence. I also tried placing the second logic into elsif. No use. I'd appreciate any help.

UPDATE:

I have this code now in the model. I deleted `if @book.save` in the controller. When I save, the page does nothing, but the button remains frozen at clicked.

```rb
validate :existing_book, on: :create
# also tried before_create :existing_book

def existing_book

    existing_book = Book.find_by(author: self.author, publisher: self.publisher)

    existing_book ||= Book.find_by(name: self.name, genre: self.genre)

    if existing_book.nil?
      self.save
      redirect_to book_url(self)
    else
      throw(:abort)
      redirect_to new_book_url(self)
      errors.add("matching record exists")
    end
end
```

I added throw(:abort) after reading that in Rails 5+, returning false doesn't abort the process (it didn't when I tried it).

Error message: `No template found for BooksController#create, rendering head :no_content`. So I'm guessing @book.save should be in the controller? But [before_create still saves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572007/before-create-still-saves/11572079)

--UPDATE:

I re-added .save in the controller:

```rb
    if @book.save
      redirect_to book_url(@book)
    else 
      redirect_to new_book_url(@book), alert: "Please try again."
    end
```

The model:

```rb
  before_create :existing_book

  # validate :existing_book, on: :create

  def existing_book

    existing_book = Book.find_by(author: self.author, publisher: self.publisher)

    existing_book ||= Book.find_by(name: self.name, genre: self.genre)

    if existing_book != nil
      return false
    end

  end
```

The record still gets created. Same when before_save instead of before_create.

Comment: `throw` has absolutely nothing to do with validations or `ActiveModel::Errors`. `throw` is control flow. Its used together with `catch` to break out of deeply nested constructs during normal execution. Unlike exceptions you don't need to catch in the same lexical scope. http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/tut_exceptions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `validate` method should not call `save`, `redirect`, or `raise` any error. Those are handled by the controller code. The model-level `validate` should either add errors to the instance, or do nothing at all.

For example (and simplifying the code a bit to focus on the concept):

```
  validate :existing_book

  def existing_book
    existing_book = Book.find_by(name: self.name)

    if existing_book != nil
      errors.add(:name, "already taken")
    end

  end
```

And then testing it out:

```
existing_name = Book.first.name
new_book = Book.new(name: existing_name)
new_book.valid? # false
new_book.errors.full_messages # => ["name already taken"]
new_book.save # false
```

In the controller, for example:

```
   book = Book.new(book_params)
   if book.save
     # redirect to page on success
   else
     @errors = book.errors.full_messages
     # render the `new` page, showing the errors 
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `before_create` filter to your model. Let's suppose you name it `check_existing_records`.

```
before_create :check_existing_records # add this line to the top of your model
```

You want to add code inside the body of your method which will return false in case it is detected that the new instance should not be saved. Something like:

```
def check_existing_records
  existing_book = Book.find_by(author: self.author, publisher: self.publisher)
  # in case no book with same author and publisher was found, check for book
  # with same name and same genre.
  existing_book ||= Book.find_by(name: self.name, genre: self.genre)
  # returns false if there is an existing record which matches these conditions
  # and stops persistence of record in the database
  existing_book.nil?
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I basically copy-pasted it in my code. Where should I add the second part? When I place it in my model, records get created regardless of existing records, and when I place it in controller, it generates "undefined check_existing_records" error.

Comment: You should add the 'before_create' to the top of your model, under your "has_many, belongs_to' declarations and above the method declarations. You should add the second part to your model.

Comment: Thank you. Record still gets created even if it matches existing one. I checked whether the function itself is getting called; it is. I tried return nil and return false alone and the record still gets created. Do I need a different way to exit if matching record exists?

Comment: Are you calling .save elsewhere? Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572007/before-create-still-saves/11572079

Comment: Yes, I call ```if @book.save``` in the controller, in the create method. I read the post, but I'm still confused. If I get rid of save, how would it save?

Comment: I've updated the question. Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: You should keep the 'before_create' as it was and save the book in the controller, then do something (in the controller) like 'if @book.save {...} else {...} end', as '@book.save' will return 'false' if the book was not saved, and returning 'false' in a 'before_save' callback will prevent the persistence of a record in the database.

Comment: Take a look at this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572007/before-create-still-saves?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find_or_create_by` method for this:

```
book = Book.find_or_create_by(author: @book.author, publisher: @book.publisher)
```

This command will find any existing book with the matching author and publisher or created a new book record if there is no such entry.