# How to check whether similar record exists - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I check whether matching record exists, before creating a new record, with this:

```rb
if !Book.exists?(name: @book.name) and !Book.exists?(author: @book.author)
```

Is there a way to check whether ***similar*** record exists? In SQL, like LIKE %name%.

-- Addition. The above was in the controller. It had "self" instead of "@book", so it may have been confusing. Sorry. When I do this in the model, like below, it doesn't prevent the record from being created even though matching record exists, so I had moved it to the controller:

```rb
before_create :check_existing_records

def check_existing_records

  existing_book = Book.find_by(author: self.author, publisher: self.publisher)

  existing_book ||= Book.find_by(name: self.name, genre: self.genre)

  existing_book.nil?

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do LIKE queries like so: `Book.exists?("name LIKE ?", "%#{self.name}%")`. Note that it's important to use a "parameterized" query (the ?) to avoid SQL injection

You can see this doc about it https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.2/security.html#sql-injection

Comment: Thank you. I seem to get this error: ```undefined method `name' ```

Comment: @amazingbot I mean, you included `self.name` in your question so I assumed it existed. if you want help on that, can you show more context - where is this code being called from?

Comment: Sorry, I added details in the question.

Comment: You should use a validation, not before_create. You can see here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

Comment: I tried ```validate :check_existing_records, on: :create```, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried deleting @book.save in the controller, per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572007/before-create-still-saves/11572079, but now it returns ```No template found for BooksController#create, rendering head :no_content``` in the terminal (on the webpage it's just frozen).

Comment: No offense but you're kind of all over the place here. If the `validate` isn't working you should edit your question to show your attempt, or ideally just make a new question. You'll get answers much quicker that way then by providing sparse details in comments. There are no magic bullets to these questions - there are multiple ways a thing can fail to work.

Comment: Based on your comment, I suppose premise is that validate should be working, and that the code I have in the question is correct? That there's something else causing the error. One source I found said calling method in model this way and returning false doesn't throw error (rails 5+), so I had tried throw(:abort) (which didn't work and which I should stop if the code in my question is correct)

Comment: @amazingbot I linked you to the rails guide on custom validations. As you can see there, you need to use `errors.add` to prevent the record from saving. `throw(:abort)` is completely wrong, `throw` doesn't even have to do with errors in Ruby. I recommend just making a separate question about this and showing your code. Since the issue you're having is separate from what you originally asked about (how to make LIKE queries)

Comment: Almost forgot about the original question. Thank you for your help, Max. I will make a new question (after trying more to work it out).

Comment: Oh forgot to add -- tried errors.add before and didn't work... it's fine, I'll ask a separate question (again, after trying more)

Comment: Very sorry, I actually asked this question a few days ago. Still unresolved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67293001/filtering-at-create-rails

Answer (score 1):

You can also create LIKE queries by using Arel:

```
name = 'Moby'
Book.where(Book.arel_table[:name].matches("%#{name}%"))
    .exists?
```

The cool part about using Arel to create SQL programatically instead of a SQL string is that you can roll it into a flexible class method:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  # @return [ActiveRecord::Relation]
  # @example
  #   Book.matches(name: 'foo').exists?
  def self.matches(**kwargs)
    kwargs.map do |key, value|
      arel_table[key].matches("%#{value}%")
    end.then do |conditions| 
      where(*conditions)
    end
  end
end
```

This lets you use `LIKE` queries on any column and any model.